# Centers node in a cluster

Tags: graphviz, dot

I try to draw multiple finite state diagram in graphviz in only one diagram
For now i have this :

```
digraph D {
    
    rankdir = LR;
    node [shape = circle]

    subgraph automaton_1 {
        invis [shape = point style = invis]
        0 [label =<S<SUB>0</SUB>>]
        1 [label =<S<SUB>1</SUB>>]
        2 [label =<S<SUB>2</SUB>>]
        3 [label =<S<SUB>3</SUB>>]
        4 [label =<S<SUB>4</SUB>>]
        5 [label =<S<SUB>5</SUB>> peripheries = 2]
    }

    invis -> 0
    0 -> 1[label = "a"]
    1 -> 2[label = "b"]
    0 -> 3[label = "b"]
    3 -> 4[label = "c"]
    2 -> 5[label = "d"]
    4 -> 5[label = "d"]

    subgraph automaton_2 {
        b_invis [shape = point style = invis]
        b_0 [label =<S<SUB>0</SUB>'>]
        b_1 [label =<S<SUB>1</SUB>'>]
        b_2 [label =<S<SUB>2</SUB>'>]
        b_3 [label =<S<SUB>3</SUB>'>]
        b_4 [label =<S<SUB>4</SUB>'>]
        b_5 [label =<S<SUB>5</SUB>'> peripheries = 2]
    }

    b_invis -> b_0
    b_0 -> b_1[label = "a"]
    b_1 -> b_2[label = "b"]
    b_0 -> b_3[label = "b"]
    b_3 -> b_4[label = "c"]
    b_2 -> b_5[label = "d"]
    b_4 -> b_5[label = "d"]

    invis -> b_invis[constraint=false, style=invis]
}
```

which give this result : [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5u6z.png)

But i want to have two independently aligned diagram, aligned like this : [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVI0O.png)

Comment: Do you want 2 pages, 2 distinct output files, or something else?

Comment: Juste the two diagram, one above the other but align like the second image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your `subgraph`s into actual clusters by adding `cluster_` to their names. Inside clusters nodes from each of the subgraphs won't be affected by each other.

Here's the corrected code and the result (note that I've also added `peripheries=0` for each cluster to remove borders:

```
digraph D {
    rankdir = LR;
    node [shape = circle]

    subgraph cluster_automaton_1 {
        peripheries=0
        invis [shape = point style = invis]
        0 [label =<S<SUB>0</SUB>>]
        1 [label =<S<SUB>1</SUB>>]
        2 [label =<S<SUB>2</SUB>>]
        3 [label =<S<SUB>3</SUB>>]
        4 [label =<S<SUB>4</SUB>>]
        5 [label =<S<SUB>5</SUB>> peripheries = 2]
    }

    invis -> 0
    0 -> 1[label = "a"]
    1 -> 2[label = "b"]
    0 -> 3[label = "b"]
    3 -> 4[label = "c"]
    2 -> 5[label = "d"]
    4 -> 5[label = "d"]

    subgraph cluster_automaton_2 {
        peripheries=0

        b_invis [shape = point style = invis]
        b_0 [label =<S<SUB>0</SUB>'>]
        b_1 [label =<S<SUB>1</SUB>'>]
        b_2 [label =<S<SUB>2</SUB>'>]
        b_3 [label =<S<SUB>3</SUB>'>]
        b_4 [label =<S<SUB>4</SUB>'>]
        b_5 [label =<S<SUB>5</SUB>'> peripheries = 2]
    }

    b_invis -> b_0
    b_0 -> b_1[label = "a"]
    b_1 -> b_2[label = "b"]
    b_0 -> b_3[label = "b"]
    b_3 -> b_4[label = "c"]
    b_2 -> b_5[label = "d"]
    b_4 -> b_5[label = "d"]

    invis -> b_invis[constraint=false, style=invis]
}
```

[image]